# parenting a follow path to a curve Goe another direction

Tags: rendering, mesh, rigging, parent, path

When parenting a rig to a path the parenting line wanders off in space instead of the line attaching to the path

Comment: pls provide blend file since we have no idea what your settings are, thx

Comment: Your object needs to be at the center of the scene if you want it to stick at the beginning of the curve once you give it the *Follow Path* constraint, to do that select your object and press Alt G, is it your problem here? If not please show some screenshots or as Chris says, share your file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, Kevin, .. welcome.. we'll be able to give you a specific answer if you provide us with enough detail. We need some indication of where the origins of your objects are, relative to their geometry, and one another. A share on https://blend-exchange.com/ would probably get this fixed pronto. Please edit, or this post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'